# Clathrate Compounds with Quinone

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I prepared a compound "$\ce{SO2}$-Quinolclathrate" by dissolving hydroquinone and sodium sulfite with hydrochloric acid in warm water.

After this, I tested a little sample of the product on a flame and it vaporised, following which I smelled the gas. I am supposed to define this gas and my prediction is that this could be $\ce{SO2}$(with orange flame).

Clathrate compounds include a trapping system with guest molecules (held "guest" in cages) and the host (hydroquinone here). 
$\ce{SO2}$ is guest in the cages of hydroquinone and the gas is held due to crystal lattice forces. Does this mean there are no bonds?

What can be the reason for $\ce{SO2}$ vaporizing?

Additionally, the product was added to starch/iodine solution to find out if it is soluble in that solution and it is so. What can be the reason of this solubility.

Answer (score 1):

Palin, D. E.; Powell, H. M. "Hydrogen Bond Linking of Quinol Molecules," Nature  156, 334 (1946), and DOI: 10.1039/DF9694800181

White aqueous starch/iod$ide$ tests for oxidizing agents by turning brown, liberated iodine and ionic oligomers intercalated within amylose starch (linear).  Amylopetcin (branched) gives red.  The mix is purple-brown.  Purple-brown aqueous starch/iod$ine$ tests for reducing agents by the reverse.